# Google Maps API - Closest points - Changing the sort order

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3, google-api, maps

I have a number of employees in various locations.  When I receive a job, I want to assign it to the nearest employee. So in this case, the assignment is in zip code 06810.  The current code below first ranks the straight line distance using Latitude and Longitude. Then using google directions, the actual driving distance in miles is calculated but is still sorted by straight line distance.  I would like the results sorted by actual driving distance like in the second group.  Anyone know how to do this?  Thanks

```
Original Results - http://vince.netau.net/vince.html    Using Zip Code 06810
Jen Alexander process 3:41.159977,-73.982356:      50348.52      54.3 Miles
Richard Henderson process 11:40.858696,-73.297249: 59009.38        92 Miles
Jim Thomas process 0:41.041599,-74.019554:         60252.91      55.5 Miles
Don James process 2:40.997704,-74.050598:          65365.08      59.5 Miles
John Smith process 1:40.986584,-74.290207:         82405.22        74 Miles
Al Bundy process 8:40.804319,-74.122668:           84834.76      71.2 Miles
Tim Hager process 7:40.691845,-73.969104:          87569.35      69.9 Miles
Ken Roberts process 5:40.754302,-74.409713:       105950.12      92.8 Miles
Vince Patera process 9:40.562019,-74.452335:      123497.86       101 Miles
Thomas Glenn process 10:40.291759,-74.343231:     142031.60       109 Miles
Tom Jones process 4:40.001475,-75.0268:           202567.94       153 Miles
Kevin James process 6:39.82534,-74.919937:        212467.19       155 Miles

Results I want
Jen Alexander process 3:41.159977,-73.982356:      50348.52      54.3 Miles
Jim Thomas process 0:41.041599,-74.019554:         60252.91      55.5 Miles
Don James process 2:40.997704,-74.050598:          65365.08      59.5 Miles
Tim Hager process 7:40.691845,-73.969104:          87569.35      69.9 Miles
Al Bundy process 8:40.804319,-74.122668:           84834.76      71.2 Miles
John Smith process 1:40.986584,-74.290207:         82405.22        74 Miles  
Richard Henderson process 11:40.858696,-73.297249: 59009.38        92 Miles
Ken Roberts process 5:40.754302,-74.409713:       105950.12      92.8 Miles
Vince Patera process 9:40.562019,-74.452335:      123497.86       101 Miles
Thomas Glenn process 10:40.291759,-74.343231:     142031.60       109 Miles
Tom Jones process 4:40.001475,-75.0268:           202567.94       153 Miles
Kevin James process 6:39.82534,-74.919937:        212467.19       155 Miles
```

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
     <title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Map Simple</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <style>
       html, body, #map_canvas {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         height: 100%;
       }
     </style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">     
// Store Name[0],delivery[1],Address[2],Delivery Zone[3],Coordinates[4] data from FusionTables pizza stores example
var locations = [
["Jim Thomas","no","12 Williams Rd, Montvale, NJ","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.121277,37.386799,0 -122.158012,37.4168,0 -122.158012,37.448151,0 -122.142906,37.456055,0 -122.118874,37.45224,0 -122.107544,37.437793,0 -122.102737,37.422526,0 -122.113037,37.414618,0 -122.121277,37.386799,0   </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","41.041599,-74.019554","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
["John Smith","yes","8 Craig Place, Pompton Lakes, NJ","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.200928,37.438611,0 -122.158012,37.4168,0 -122.158012,37.448151,0 -122.142906,37.456055,0 -122.144623,37.475948,0 -122.164192,37.481125,0 -122.189255,37.478673,0 -122.208481,37.468319,0 -122.201271,37.438338,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","40.986584,-74.290207","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
["Don James","no","689 Fern St, Township of Washington, NJ","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.304268,37.516534,0 -122.300835,37.505096,0 -122.262383,37.481669,0 -122.242813,37.502917,0 -122.244186,37.534232,0 -122.269249,37.550021,0 -122.291222,37.545122,0 -122.302895,37.537499,0 -122.304268,37.516534,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","40.997704,-74.050598","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png"],
["Jen Alexander","yes","45 Heritage Dr, New City, NY","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.304268,37.516534,0 -122.348557,37.538044,0 -122.359886,37.56363,0 -122.364006,37.582405,0 -122.33654,37.589207,0 -122.281609,37.570433,0 -122.291222,37.545122,0 -122.302895,37.537499,0 -122.304268,37.516534,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","41.159977,-73.982356","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],
["Tom Jones","yes","263 W. Broad St, Palmyra, NJ","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.374306,37.548933,0 -122.348557,37.538044,0 -122.359886,37.56363,0 -122.364006,37.582405,0 -122.33654,37.589207,0 -122.359543,37.59764,0 -122.372246,37.604712,0 -122.417564,37.594648,0 -122.374306,37.548933,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","40.001475, -75.026800","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
["Ken Roberts","yes","169 Main St, Madison, NJ","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.462883,37.628916,0 -122.445374,37.639247,0 -122.426147,37.648762,0 -122.405205,37.642238,0 -122.400055,37.628644,0 -122.392159,37.610696,0 -122.372246,37.604712,0 -122.417564,37.594648,0 -122.462196,37.628644,0  </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","40.754302, -74.409713","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
["Kevin James","yes","90 Tenby Chase Dr, Voorhees, NJ","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.43576,37.790795,0 -122.449493,37.801646,0 -122.425461,37.809784,0 -122.402115,37.811411,0 -122.390442,37.794593,0 -122.408295,37.79188,0 -122.434387,37.789167,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","39.825340, -74.919937","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
["Tim Hager","yes","208 Clinton Ave, Brooklyn, NY","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.463398,37.760266,0 -122.477349,37.774785,0 -122.427349,37.774785,0 -122.429237,37.763658,0 -122.46357,37.760808,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","40.691845, -73.969104","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
["Al Bundy","yes","554 Page Ave, Lyndhurst, NJ","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.418766,37.747779,0 -122.425289,37.768951,0 -122.406063,37.769901,0 -122.406063,37.749679,0 -122.418251,37.747508,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","40.804319, -74.122668","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
["Vince Patera","yes","12 Marissa Ct, Piscataway, NJ","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.121277,37.386799,0 -122.108917,37.362244,0 -122.077675,37.3385,0 -122.064285,37.378615,0 -122.069778,37.3898,0 -122.076645,37.402619,0 -122.078705,37.411619,0 -122.113037,37.414618,0 -122.121277,37.386799,0  </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","40.562019, -74.452335","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
["Thomas Glenn","no","8 Taylors Mills Rd, Manalapan, NJ","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.047119,37.33113,0 -122.065315,37.332495,0 -122.077675,37.3385,0 -122.064285,37.378615,0 -122.036819,37.385162,0 -122.006607,37.382162,0 -122.00386,37.342048,0 -122.047119,37.331403,0  </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","40.291759, -74.343231","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
["Richard Henderson","no","27 Buhl Ln, East Northport, NY","<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-121.935196,37.345051,0 -121.931076,37.294267,0 -121.871338,37.293721,0 -121.806793,37.293174,0 -121.798553,37.361426,0 -121.879578,37.36088,0 -121.934509,37.345597,0 -121.935196,37.345051,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>","40.858696, -73.297249","http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow.png"],
];
// alert(locations.length);

var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;

function initialize() {
// alert("init");
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
        {       
            zoom: 9,       
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),       
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP     
        });      
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();      
  var marker, i;      
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found "+locations.length+" locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {         
            var coordStr = locations[i][4];
        var coords = coordStr.split(",");
        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]),parseFloat(coords[1]));
            bounds.extend(pt);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({         
                            position: pt,         
                            map: map,
                icon: locations[i][5],
                            address: locations[i][2],
                            title: locations[i][0],
                            html: locations[i][0]+"<br>"+locations[i][2]+"<br><br><a href='javascript:getDirections(customerMarker.getPosition(),&quot;"+locations[i][2]+"&quot;);'>Get Directions</a>"
                            });                              
            gmarkers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {         return function() 
            {           infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);         
            }       
        })
        (marker, i));     
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds);   

}

      function codeAddress() {
        var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
            customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
        closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location,12);
            // get driving distance
            closest = closest.splice(0,12);
            calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest,12);
          } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }

function findClosestN(pt,numberOfResults) {
   var closest = [];
   document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing "+gmarkers.length+"<br>";
   for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length;i++) {
     gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt,gmarkers[i].getPosition());
     document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process "+i+":"+gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6)+":"+gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2)+"<br>";
     gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
     closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
     closest.sort(sortByDist);  
   }

   return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a,b) { 
 return (a.distance- b.distance)

}

function calculateDistances(pt,closest,numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request =    {
      origins: [pt],
      destinations: [],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    };
  for (var i=0; i<closest.length; i++) request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      for (var i = 0; i < numberOfResults; i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest["+i+"],\"click\");'>"+closest[i].title + '</a><br>' + closest[i].address+"<br>"
            + results[i].distance.text + ' appoximately '
            + results[i].duration.text + '<br><hr>';
      }
    }
  });
}

function getDirections(origin, destination) {
  var request = {
      origin:origin,
      destination:destination,
      travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('side_bar'));
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script> 
   </head>
   <body>
<table border="1"><tr><td>
     <div id="map" style="height: 600px; width:800px;"></div>
</td><td>
     <div id="side_bar"></div>
</td></tr></table>
<input id="address" type="text" value="Palo Alto, CA"></input>
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();"></input>
<div id="info"></div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the results array by the distance.

```
 results.sort(sortByDistDM);
```

where sortByDistDM is:

```
function sortByDistDM(a,b) {
   return (a.distance.value- b.distance.value)
}
```

[updated page](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_closestPlaces10sort.html)

```
function calculateDistances(pt,closest,numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request =    {
      origins: [pt],
      destinations: [],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    };
  for (var i=0; i<closest.length; i++) {
    request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function (response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title, address and index of marker in record for sorting
      for (var i=0; i<closest.length;i++) {
         results[i].title = closest[i].title;
         results[i].address = closest[i].address;
     results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      for (var i = 0; ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest["+results[i].idx_closestMark+"],\"click\");'>"+results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address+"<br>"
            + results[i].distance.text + ' appoximately '
            + results[i].duration.text + '<br><hr>';
      }
    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a,b) {
   return (a.distance.value- b.distance.value)
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder = null;
var map = null;
var customerMarker = null;
var gmarkers = [];
var closest = [];

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.6699927, -0.7274620),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker, i;
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = "found " + locations.length + " locations<br>";
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var coordStr = locations[i][4];
    var coords = coordStr.split(",");
    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]), parseFloat(coords[1]));
    bounds.extend(pt);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pt,
      map: map,
      icon: locations[i][5],
      address: locations[i][2],
      title: locations[i][0],
      html: locations[i][0] + "<br>" + locations[i][2]
    });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })
      (marker, i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

}

function codeAddress() {
  var numberOfResults = 14;
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      if (customerMarker) customerMarker.setMap(null);
      customerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
      closest = findClosestN(results[0].geometry.location, numberOfResults);
      // get driving distance
      closest = closest.splice(0, numberOfResults);
      calculateDistances(results[0].geometry.location, closest, numberOfResults);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function findClosestN(pt, numberOfResults) {
  var closest = [];
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "processing " + gmarkers.length + "<br>";
  for (var i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++) {
    gmarkers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(pt, gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += "process " + i + ":" + gmarkers[i].getPosition().toUrlValue(6) + ":" + gmarkers[i].distance.toFixed(2) + "<br>";
    gmarkers[i].setMap(null);
    closest.push(gmarkers[i]);
  }
  closest.sort(sortByDist);
  return closest;
}

function sortByDist(a, b) {
  return (a.distance - b.distance)
}

function calculateDistances(pt, closest, numberOfResults) {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  var request = {
    origins: [pt],
    destinations: [],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
    request.destinations.push(closest[i].getPosition());
  }
  service.getDistanceMatrix(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
      alert('Error was: ' + status);
    } else {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
      var outputDiv = document.getElementById('side_bar');
      outputDiv.innerHTML = '';

      var results = response.rows[0].elements;
      // save title and address in record for sorting
      for (var i = 0; i < closest.length; i++) {
        results[i].title = closest[i].title;
        results[i].address = closest[i].address;
        results[i].idx_closestMark = i;
      }
      results.sort(sortByDistDM);
      for (var i = 0;
        ((i < numberOfResults) && (i < closest.length)); i++) {
        closest[i].setMap(map);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += "<a href='javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(closest[" + results[i].idx_closestMark + "],\"click\");'>" + results[i].title + '</a><br>' + results[i].address + "<br>" + results[i].distance.text + ' appoximately ' + results[i].duration.text + '<br><hr>';
      }
    }
  });
}

function sortByDistDM(a, b) {
  return (a.distance.value - b.distance.value)
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// Store Name[0],delivery[1],Address[2],Delivery Zone[3],Coordinates[4] data from FusionTables pizza stores example
var locations = [
  ["John's Pizza", "no", "400 University Ave, Palo Alto, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.121277,37.386799,0 -122.158012,37.4168,0 -122.158012,37.448151,0 -122.142906,37.456055,0 -122.118874,37.45224,0 -122.107544,37.437793,0 -122.102737,37.422526,0 -122.113037,37.414618,0 -122.121277,37.386799,0   </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.447038,-122.160575", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "1000 Santa Cruz Ave, Menlo Park, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.200928,37.438611,0 -122.158012,37.4168,0 -122.158012,37.448151,0 -122.142906,37.456055,0 -122.144623,37.475948,0 -122.164192,37.481125,0 -122.189255,37.478673,0 -122.208481,37.468319,0 -122.201271,37.438338,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.448638,-122.187176", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John Paul's Pizzeria", "no", "1100 El Camino Real, Belmont, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.304268,37.516534,0 -122.300835,37.505096,0 -122.262383,37.481669,0 -122.242813,37.502917,0 -122.244186,37.534232,0 -122.269249,37.550021,0 -122.291222,37.545122,0 -122.302895,37.537499,0 -122.304268,37.516534,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.520436,-122.275978", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "300 E 4th Ave, San Mateo, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.304268,37.516534,0 -122.348557,37.538044,0 -122.359886,37.56363,0 -122.364006,37.582405,0 -122.33654,37.589207,0 -122.281609,37.570433,0 -122.291222,37.545122,0 -122.302895,37.537499,0 -122.304268,37.516534,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.564435,-122.322080", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "yes", "1400 Broadway Ave, Burlingame, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.374306,37.548933,0 -122.348557,37.538044,0 -122.359886,37.56363,0 -122.364006,37.582405,0 -122.33654,37.589207,0 -122.359543,37.59764,0 -122.372246,37.604712,0 -122.417564,37.594648,0 -122.374306,37.548933,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.584935,-122.366182", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "700 San Bruno Ave, San Bruno, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.462883,37.628916,0 -122.445374,37.639247,0 -122.426147,37.648762,0 -122.405205,37.642238,0 -122.400055,37.628644,0 -122.392159,37.610696,0 -122.372246,37.604712,0 -122.417564,37.594648,0 -122.462196,37.628644,0  </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.630934,-122.406883", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "300 Beach St, San Francisco, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.43576,37.790795,0 -122.449493,37.801646,0 -122.425461,37.809784,0 -122.402115,37.811411,0 -122.390442,37.794593,0 -122.408295,37.79188,0 -122.434387,37.789167,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.807628,-122.413782", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "1400 Haight St, San Francisco, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.463398,37.760266,0 -122.477349,37.774785,0 -122.427349,37.774785,0 -122.429237,37.763658,0 -122.46357,37.760808,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.770129,-122.445082", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "2400 Mission St, San Francisco, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.418766,37.747779,0 -122.425289,37.768951,0 -122.406063,37.769901,0 -122.406063,37.749679,0 -122.418251,37.747508,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.758630,-122.419082", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["JJs Express", "yes", "500 Castro St, Mountain View, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.121277,37.386799,0 -122.108917,37.362244,0 -122.077675,37.3385,0 -122.064285,37.378615,0 -122.069778,37.3898,0 -122.076645,37.402619,0 -122.078705,37.411619,0 -122.113037,37.414618,0 -122.121277,37.386799,0  </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.390040,-122.081573", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "no", "100 S Murphy Ave, Sunnyvale, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.047119,37.33113,0 -122.065315,37.332495,0 -122.077675,37.3385,0 -122.064285,37.378615,0 -122.036819,37.385162,0 -122.006607,37.382162,0 -122.00386,37.342048,0 -122.047119,37.331403,0  </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.377441,-122.030071", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "no", "1200 Curtner Ave, San Jose, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-121.935196,37.345051,0 -121.931076,37.294267,0 -121.871338,37.293721,0 -121.806793,37.293174,0 -121.798553,37.361426,0 -121.879578,37.36088,0 -121.934509,37.345597,0 -121.935196,37.345051,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.288742,-121.890765", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "yes", "700 Blossom Hill Rd, San Jose, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-121.935883,37.253287,0 -121.931076,37.294267,0 -121.871338,37.293721,0 -121.806793,37.293174,0 -121.790657,37.234702,0 -121.852455,37.223221,0 -121.935539,37.253014,0 </coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.250543,-121.846563", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "yes", "100 N Milpitas Blvd, Milpitas, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-121.947556,37.435612,0 -121.934509,37.476493,0 -121.893311,37.469409,0 -121.852798,37.429615,0 -121.843872,37.400165,0 -121.887817,37.3898,0 -121.959915,37.420345,0 -121.959915,37.427979,0 -121.948929,37.435612,0 -121.947556,37.435612,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.434113,-121.901139", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"],
  ["John's Pizza", "yes", "3300 Mowry Blvd, Fremont, CA", "<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-122.02343,37.52198,0 -122.023773,37.558731,0 -121.989784,37.573426,0 -121.959572,37.566351,0 -121.944466,37.544305,0 -121.967125,37.520891,0 -122.023087,37.522525,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>", "37.552773,-121.985153", "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"]
];
```

```css
html,
body, #map {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<table border="1" style="height:90%; width:100%;">
  <tr style="height:100%; width:100%;">
    <td valign="top" style="height:100%; width:100%;">
      <div id="map"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="side_bar" style="height: 500px; overflow:auto;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input id="address" type="text" value="Palo Alto, CA" />
<input type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress();" />
<div id="info"></div>
```